# Jira import issues via CSV - Embedded newlines in text fields are not preserved

Tags: jira, export-to-csv, import-from-csv

[This is a cross-poss from the Atlassian Jira forum](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Jira-import-issues-via-CSV-Embedded-newlines-in-text-fields-are/qaq-p/905477)

I am migrating issues from one Jira instance (the source) to another Jira instance (the destination).

I cannot use the **Project Configurator** add-on since the source & destination versions are different.

I am exporting issues to a CSV and then importing the CSV to the destination.

I have several multi-line text fields in which the data contains newlines.

The CSV is created correctly (the data in the columns is enclosed in double quotes to protect the embedded CR/LF).
[See the Jira reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver0711/importing-data-from-csv-955168458.html)

However, after the **successful** import via CSV to the destination Jira, the CR/LF are gone and the text field contains all lines concatenated.

The source field:

```
MyValue-1
MyValue-2
MyValue-3
```

Date in the export/import CSV:

```
"MyValue-1<CR><LF>
MyValue-2<CR><LF>
MyValue-3<CR><LF>
"
```

Destination field:

```
MyValue-1MyValue2MyValue-3
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I have received some input from Atlassian via the forum (in the thread mentioned in my question). I will post definite answers when I have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to Atlassian support and they came back with the answer that it's a known bug:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-46365

In the bug description they suggest 2 workarounds. I checked the 1st one and **it works**!

Answer (score 1):

There is another ADD-on called Configuration Manager (Botron) its on market place. The add-on is helpful. May be you can give a try.

Thanks